# VBA Why is my subscript out of range?

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-statements

I'm using the code below to parse a string and set sections of it into an array. However, I am getting a subscript out of range error on the line indicated below. What could I be doing wrong?

```
vals = Array("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")

Set r = Range("B2").End(xlDown)

For Each x In Range("B2", r)
    k = 0

    For i = 1 To Len(x)
        char = Mid(x, i, 1)

        Select Case Asc(char)
            Case 48 To 57
                ' Error on line below (Run-time error9: Subscript out of range)
                vals(k) = vals(k) + char
            Case Else
                Erase vals
                k = k + 1
        End Select
    Next i

    Set cll = x.End(xlToLeft)

    cll.Value = vals(0) + "-" + vals(1) + "-" + vals(2) + "T" + vals(3) + ":" + vals(4) + ":" + vals(5) + "Z"
Next x
```

Comment: After you erase `vals` once it's not valid anymore.

Comment: I get the same error after removing that line

Comment: Apparently there are more reasons for `k` to be outside of the allowed indices for `vals`. Please debug your code.

Comment: Based on the first line of your code `vals = Array("",....` the variable `vals` is an array of 15 elements starting with element `0`  through element `14`. If the line `vals(k)...` is causing you problems then it might be that `k` is at this time `> 14`. So, any time a cell in column `B` contains more than 15 non-numeric characters you will get this error.